# How to disable return key and call another function when click on Return Key in keyboard Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift4

I already set the "return" key in keyboard to "Send",by using this line `chatTextView.returnKeyType = .send`.What I want is disable the "Send" button when the textView is equal to placeholder text,the "Send" button disable,if not then call another function when click on "Send" button.

Currently my code is look like this:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if TextView.text == self.placeholderText {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

But it doesnt not get any effect.The "Send" button enable at default,and the "Send" button didnt call my function,but just go to next line instead.

And when click on "Send" button I wish to call `myFunction()` which is a networking call.But I just dont know where to access the "Send" Button

I see a lot of question is talk about `TextField` but none of them is `TextView`,please kindly help on this

Answer (score 0):

You forget the _

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text != placeHolder && text == "\n" {
        self.myFunction()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: bro,how to call another function when click on the `Send` button?

Comment: call it before return

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (text == "\n") {
        myFunction()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if TextView.text == self.placeholderText && text == "\n" {
            return false

        }else if text == "\n" && text != self.placeholderText{
                 textView.resignFirstResponder()
                 myFunction()
                 return false
}
        return true
    }
```

Please try this.